# Problem with DSolve function argument

Tags: differential-equations

today when i try this

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 *Cos[x]}, y[x], x]
```

i think i'v already argument the function `y`, but still got:

> `DSolve::dvnoarg: The function y appears with no arguments.`

and

> `DSolve[{Cos[x] y[x]^2 == (y^2 cos[x])[x]}, y[x], x]`

i don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get

```
{{y[x] -> 1/(-C[1] - Sin[x])}}
```

Try to `Clear` the variables or restart the kernel.